# Assigning to a constant variable in an constant expression

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

My knowledge in this is limited, the situation is as following:

```
const std::map<char*, int> map;

constexpr void Foo()
{
    map["foo"] = 0;
}
```

This does not compile, as it complains that I cannot assign a value to a constant variable. But I was under the impression that if the function was sorted out in compilation time one could set the value of a constant value.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What if someone calls the function twice?

Comment: Do you want a way to initialize a `const map` ?

Comment: @PaoloM Good question, although it should not happen, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not directly, I was hoping that I could insert a few entries in compile time, but as I said my knowledge in this is very limited so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: BTW, `constexpr` functions are not always evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, this could explain it, although it would be sad, is there a way to ensure/force it?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to initialize a structure at compile time, is if it has a `constexpr` constructor. `std::map` does not have a `constexpr` constructor. Also I don't think it could have one because it is partially heap allocated, and `new`, `malloc` etc. are not `constexpr`.

You can get kind of close doing something like this: (C++11)

```
struct my_pair {
    const char * first;
    int second;
};

constexpr my_pair my_map[] = {  {"foo", 5},
                {"bar", 10},
                {"baz", 20} };

int main() {}
```

You could then build a `std::map` when your program starts up from this array.

If you really want the array to be sorted by key at compile-time, in C++11 standard, I guess I would try to implement the sort using template metaprogramming. You could do it using templates / variadic pack expansions without much difficulty, but it would probably take an hour or two to write it all out and get it working, depending how proficient you are with templates. You would then have to format the key, value pairs as template parameters in your code, not as array elements, so it will get a little messy.

In C++14 it might be possible / easier to do the sort in a `constexpr` function, I'm not sure.